# Как сделать кнопку поделиться в директ инстаграма?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

В одной компании сделали мобильное приложение и у них есть кнопка поделиться в директ а вот я ищу везде не могу найти как это делать для сайта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вітаю! Знайшли рішення?!

Comment: насколько я находил, что нет такого для сайта. даже в виджете яндекса на тот момент (середина 2020) не было для инстаграма.